# Появление кнопки при наведении на картинку

Tags: html, css, bootstrap

Подскажите,что нужно написать что бы при наведении на картинку появилась кнопка заказать консультацию?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```css
.range-txt {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0%;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  color: #000;
  font-size: 20px;
  padding: 10px 10px 10px 16px;
  text-align: center;
}
.position-rage-bottom {
  padding-bottom: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="col-sm-4 img-responsive">
  <img src="images/range2.png">
  <span class="range-txt position-rage-bottom">
  Мебель для персонала<br> 
  <strong>от 2 012 руб.</strong>
  </span>
</div>
```

Comment: а где в разметке кнопка?

Comment: @Grundy - ее нет, потому что еще не навели мышку на картинку

Comment: но в разметке-то она должна быть, просто скрытая иначе как вы ее показывать собрались?

Comment: <div class="col-sm-4 img-responsive">
  <img src="images/range2.png">
  <span class="range-txt position-rage-bottom">
  Мебель для персонала<br> 
  <strong>от 2 012 руб.</strong><a>Заказать консультацию</a>
  </span>
</div>

Comment: @Grundy - пардон, забыл поставить ":)"

Comment: @Igor :-D а я даже не понял, что это не топик стартер ответил

Comment: @ChromeChrome обновляйте код в посте

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Отверстайте вашу кнопку поверх вашей картинки, (например используя position absulute) потом задайте ей свойство display:none; после чего на родительский блок, у вас это кажется col-sm-4 img-responsive (я бы добавил класс отдельный) повешайте псевдокласс ховер, а уже в этом псевдоклассе задайте стиль для кнопки с display:block. Т.е. при наведении CSS будет менять свойство display.
Вот пример ховера:

```
.col-sm-4.img-responsive:hover .mybutton{
display:block;
}
```

ну и набросок кнопки:

```
.mybutton{
position:absolute;
top:50%;
leftблаблабла...
главное тут:
display:none;

}
```

Написал бы подробнее, но извините, надеюсь это вам поможет...

Answer (score 1):

мне кажется так будет лучше, потому что на "display" "transition " не будет срабатывать кнопка будет просто выскакивать а не появляться плавно

```css
.img-responsive {
    position: relative;
    width: 296px;
    height: 300px;
    
}

.range-txt {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0%;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    color: #000;
    font-size: 20px;
    padding: 10px 10px 10px 16px;
    text-align: center;
}

.position-rage-bottom {
    padding-bottom: 20px;
}

button {
    opacity: 0;
    position: absolute;
    width: 200px;
    height: 40px;
    top: 100px;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .3);
    left: calc(50% - 100px);
    color:#fff;
    transition: opacity .3s;
}

.img-responsive:hover button {
    opacity: 1;
    transition: opacity .3s;
}
```

```html
 <div class="col-sm-4 img-responsive">
  <img src="http://www.mydoska.com/images/normal/491968.jpg">
  <span class="range-txt position-rage-bottom">
        Мебель для персонала<br> 
        <strong>от 2 012 руб.</strong>
  </span>
  <button>Заказать консультацию</button>
</div>
```