# Как сделать, чтоб при наведении на блок, блок затемнялся и показывался скрытый текст этого блока

Tags: css, вёрстка

Текста не должно быть видно. Покажите просто пример, то я вообще не понимаю как сделать такое.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Появление кнопки при наведении на картинку](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/472613/%d0%9f%d0%be%d1%8f%d0%b2%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%ba%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%bf%d0%ba%d0%b8-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8-%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b8-%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d0%ba%d0%b0%d1%80%d1%82%d0%b8%d0%bd%d0%ba%d1%83)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```css
#photos {
   /* Prevent vertical gaps */
   line-height: 0;
      
   -webkit-column-count: 2;
   -webkit-column-gap:   0px;
   -moz-column-count:    2;
   -moz-column-gap:      0px;
   column-count:         2;
   column-gap:           0px;
   
}
#photos img {  
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

a.darken {
    display: inline-block;
    background: black;
    padding: 0;
    position:relative;
 
}

a.darken img {
    display: block;
}

a.darken:hover img {
    opacity: 0.3;           
}
a.darken span{
    visibility:hidden; 
    font-size:16px;
      position: absolute;
      top: 50%;
      left: 50%;
      -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
      transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
      line-height: 100%;
}
a.darken:hover span{
    color:#fff; 
    visibility:visible;    
}
```

```html
<section id="photos">
  <a href="/portfolio/test1.shtml" class="darken"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/cFUOEtW.jpg"><span>GALLERY ONE</span></a>
  <a href="/portfolio/test2.shtml" class="darken"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/cFUOEtW.jpg"><span>GALLERY TWO</span></a>
  <a href="/portfolio/test3.shtml" class="darken"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/cFUOEtW.jpg"><span>GALLERY THREE</span></a>
  <a href="/portfolio/test4.shtml" class="darken"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/cFUOEtW.jpg"><span>GALLERT FOUR</span></a>
</section>
```

Answer (score 1):

```css
.text {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  font-size: 200%;
  background-image: url(http://womanwiki.ru/s/images/thumb/c/c5/Fitonyashka2.jpg/300px-Fitonyashka2.jpg);
  color: transparent;
}

.text:hover {
  background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, .7), rgba(0, 0, 0, .7)), url(http://womanwiki.ru/s/images/thumb/c/c5/Fitonyashka2.jpg/300px-Fitonyashka2.jpg);
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="text">
  Lorem ipsum
</div>
```