# Выезжающий текст при наведении на картинку

Tags: html, css

Здравствуйте! Как сделать так, чтобы при наведении на картинку, заголовок плавно выезжал в самый верх, при этом фон растягивался по высоте. После этого посередине картинки должна появиться надпись "read more". 
Блок с картинкой не фиксированных размеров и фон полупрозрачный. Так же высота заголовка, который над картинкой (см. изображение) тоже не фиксированная, тк текста может быть больше.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Заранее спасибо!

Comment: превратили ruSO в халявное средство получения нужного ...вы покажите ваши наработки ...что вы уже сделали и что не получилось

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Появление кнопки при наведении на картинку](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/472613/%d0%9f%d0%be%d1%8f%d0%b2%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%ba%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%bf%d0%ba%d0%b8-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8-%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b8-%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d0%ba%d0%b0%d1%80%d1%82%d0%b8%d0%bd%d0%ba%d1%83)

Comment: Максим Ленский, тогда не следует отвечать на подобные вопросы....

Answer (score 1):

Поделюсь одним интересным решением:

```css
.special {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  margin: 20px;
  border: 20px solid #f1f1f1;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 1px 1px 2px #d5d5d5;
  -moz-box-shadow: 1px 1px 2px #d5d5d5;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 2px #d5d5d5;
}

.special img {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  -webkit-transform: scaleY(1);
  -moz-transform: scaleY(1);
  -ms-transform: scaleY(1);
  -o-transform: scaleY(1);
  transform: scaleY(1);
  -webkit-transition: all 0.7s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all 0.7s ease-in-out;
  -ms-transition: all 0.7s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: all 0.7s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 0.7s ease-in-out;
}

.special .s-p {
  position: absolute;
  overflow: hidden;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s linear;
  -moz-transition: all 0.5s linear;
  -ms-transition: all 0.5s linear;
  -o-transition: all 0.5s linear;
  transition: all 0.5s linear;
  -moz-opacity: 0;
  -khtml-opacity: 0;
  opacity: 0;
}

.special .s-p h3 {
  margin: 0 10px;
  padding: 10px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #d5d5d5;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 1em;
  font-weight: 700;
  color: #333;
  -webkit-transform: scale(0);
  -moz-transform: scale(0);
  -ms-transform: scale(0);
  -o-transform: scale(0);
  transform: scale(0);
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s linear;
  -moz-transition: all 0.5s linear;
  -ms-transition: all 0.5s linear;
  -o-transition: all 0.5s linear;
  transition: all 0.5s linear;
  -moz-opacity: 0;
  -khtml-opacity: 0;
  opacity: 0;
}

.special .s-p p {
  padding: 10px;
  font-size: 1em;
  line-height: 1.2;
  font-weight: normal;
  text-align: center;
  color: #333;
  -webkit-transform: scale(0);
  -moz-transform: scale(0);
  -ms-transform: scale(0);
  -o-transform: scale(0);
  transform: scale(0);
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s linear;
  -moz-transition: all 0.5s linear;
  -ms-transition: all 0.5s linear;
  -o-transition: all 0.5s linear;
  transition: all 0.5s linear;
  -moz-opacity: 0;
  -khtml-opacity: 0;
  opacity: 0;
}

.special:hover img {
  -webkit-transform: scale(10);
  -moz-transform: scale(10);
  -ms-transform: scale(10);
  -o-transform: scale(10);
  transform: scale(10);
  -moz-opacity: 0;
  -khtml-opacity: 0;
  opacity: 0;
}

.special:hover .s-p {
  -moz-opacity: 1;
  -khtml-opacity: 1;
  opacity: 1;
}

.special:hover h3,
.special:hover p {
  -webkit-transform: scale(1);
  -moz-transform: scale(1);
  -ms-transform: scale(1);
  -o-transform: scale(1);
  transform: scale(1);
  -moz-opacity: 1;
  -khtml-opacity: 1;
  opacity: 1;
}

a.button {
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #FFFFFF, #E6E6E6) #F5F5F5 repeat-x;
  border-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) #B3B3B3;
  border-radius: 4px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 1px;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2) inset, 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
  color: #333333;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  font-size: 14px;
  width: 120px;
  line-height: 20px;
  margin: 20px auto;
  padding: 4px 12px;
  text-align: center;
  text-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.75);
  vertical-align: middle;
  position: relative;
  -webkit-transition-duration: 0.3s;
  transition-duration: 0.3s;
  -webkit-transition-property: -webkit-transform;
  transition-property: transform;
  -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
  -webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
  -ms-transform: translateZ(0);
  transform: translateZ(0);
  box-shadow: 0 0 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
}

a.button:before {
  pointer-events: none;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
  content: '';
  top: 100%;
  left: 5%;
  height: 10px;
  width: 90%;
  opacity: 0;
  background: -webkit-radial-gradient(center, ellipse, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.35) 0%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 80%);
  background: radial-gradient(ellipse at center, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.35) 0%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 80%);
  -webkit-transition-duration: 0.3s;
  transition-duration: 0.3s;
  -webkit-transition-property: -webkit-transform, opacity;
  transition-property: transform, opacity;
}

a.button:hover {
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-2px);
  -ms-transform: translateY(-2px);
  transform: translateY(-2px);
}

a.button:hover:before {
  opacity: 1;
  -webkit-transform: translateY(2px);
  -ms-transform: translateY(2px);
  transform: translateY(2px);
}
```

```html
<div class="special"><img src="https://sochinyshka.ru/wp-content/uploads/2017/09/Pushkin.jpg">
  <div class="s-p">
    <h3>ФОНТАНУ БАХЧИСАРАЙСКОГО ДВОРЦА</h3>
    <p>Фонтан любви, фонтан живой!<br>Принес я в дар тебе две розы.<br>Люблю немолчный говор твой<br>И поэтические слезы.<br><br><b><i>Александр Сергеевич Пушкин</i></b></p>
    <a class="button" href="#">Перейти</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Примерно так ..дальше сами доработаете

```css
*{
  margin:0; padding:0;
}
img{
  display:block; max-width:100%;
}
.img{
  display:inline-block;
  position:relative;
  overflow:hidden;
}
.link{
  position:absolute;
  top:0; bottom:0;
  left:0; right:0;
  margin:auto;
  width:50%;
  height:50px;
  line-height:50px;
  color:#cc0000;
  font-size:1.3em;
  background:#fffbbb;
  text-align:center;
  visibility:hidden;
  transition:all .5s linear;
}
.img:hover .link{
  visibility:visible;
}
.container{
  position:absolute;
  bottom:0;
  z-index:100;
  width:100%;
  background:#fffbbb;
  overflow:hidden;height:0;
  transition:all .6s linear;
}
.img:hover .container{
 height:auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="img">
  <div class="link">read more</div>
  <img src="http://luxfon.com/pic/201306/800x600/luxfon.com-21678.jpg" alt="" width="320px">
  <div class="container">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Sint quis et neque corrupti consequuntur voluptatem ipsam earum quas cupiditate dolore!
  </div>
</div>

<div class="img">
  <div class="link">read more</div>
  <img src="http://luxfon.com/pic/201306/800x600/luxfon.com-21678.jpg" alt="" width="640px">
  <div class="container">
    Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quo, dolores mollitia voluptas praesentium recusandae non, asperiores quisquam dolor sapiente voluptate soluta excepturi minima atque itaque laborum velit animi odio est libero saepe! Voluptas
    magni odit cumque laboriosam illum ducimus expedita nulla minima debitis quam modi ut voluptatem, fugiat at unde.
  </div>
</div>
```